# How to add an id to canvas generated by Konva?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

Is there a way to somehow add unique `id` to the canvas generated by konva? Its nested inside the `'container'` div and one more div. It's pretty difficult to get to it, would be much easier if there would be a way to add `id` to it.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @lavrton Well, unfortunately I have to save somewhere the relation to this canvas, since Im using few more tools which actually destroys whole state of the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public API for that yet, but with the last version of `konva@4.0.10` you can do this:

```
const canvas = layer.getCanvas()._canvas;
canvas.id = 'new-id';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get a canvas you could select it via

```
const konvaCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
```

and then try to add an id by doing this

```
konvaCanvas.setAttribute("id", "whatever-id-you-want");
```

Let me know if this works
Have a good one!

Comment: thanks but its not the best solution there available :(